# User settings [discord.py]

Tags: python

I've been working on this code for a discord bot that allows you toggle passive mode on and off.
When you enable it, it adds your user id to a list of passive mode users and removes it when disabled.
When I run this command, nothing happens, and the text file isn't overwritten. Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

```py
@client.command()
async def passive(ctx, value: bool):
  user_id = str(ctx.author.id)
  if value:
    with open('passive.txt', 'w') as a:
      if user_id in a.read():
        await ctx.channel.send('You are already in passive mode!')
      else:
        a.write(f'{user_id}\n')
        await ctx.channel.send('Passive mode successfully enabled!')
      a.close()
  else:
    with open('passive.txt', 'r') as r:
      lines = r.readlines()
      r.close()
    with open('passive.txt', 'w') as d:
      for line in lines:
        if line.strip('\n') != (user_id):
          d.write(line)
          await ctx.channel.send('No more passive mode for you')
        else: 
          await ctx.channel.send('You are already not in passive mode!')
      d.close()
```

Comment: if you would like your code to run faster in the future and to support many more users, you should use a database system. for example, I would recommend TinyDB or SQLite for python, both are easy to use and understand, and would make things much simpler in the future. using text files to store information is not a very efficient method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That isn't really a discord.py questions.**
first you should learn to read the err message in your IDE or debugger.

and change `with open('passive.txt', 'w') as a:` to `with open('passive.txt', 'w+') as a:`

**You can't read and write at the same time with `'w'`, but `'w+'` will do it**

I tested your code with w+, it's work fine for file I/O but not the toggle.

**I suggest you test the text IO first**, if it work, put it into your bot.
Maybe you should simplify your question and post it as a python question (without the part of discord.py)

[image: The IO mode]

here's the I/O doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o